# add up widths of elements until a ceiling is meet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a header text changes length. I also have a set of logos that have a static length.

**The problem:** When the header (text) gets too long or short the logos either do not use the space effectively or the logos end up going to another line.

**Solution in Simple Terms** I want a script that adds up the width of logos one-by-one and when a certain width is meet it stops showing the logos.

## For Example:

- The logos are hidden.
- The header space is 400px
- The container is 800px
- remainder space is 400px
- the script would add up the logos one-by-one until the 400px was meet
- If the 4th logos was at 450px it would not show that logo or any other logo after.

http://jsfiddle.net/FDkRN/

I tried what I know, but I am still new to js so any help would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is unclear what you want - you may be able to achieve this in CSS if you set overflow-y: hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the width of heading, so its does not cross the boundary and set your logo container to hide the overflow content

```
h5 { width: 800px; }
#logos ul { white-space: nowrap; width: 400px; overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: yes, but in some cases partial views of a logo will be visible

Comment: wow, I was wrong. Thanks. Didn't know the overflow would hide the whole element. I thought it would only hide that part that was beyond the width.

Answer (score 2):

Does this achieve what you are wanting to do, without the use of javascript?

http://jsfiddle.net/FDkRN/3/

I'm assuming #container would be a #header type div - so you have hide the overflow on that.

Comment: The problem is that half the logo or a quarter of a logo will visible.

Comment: in my example, a, b, c, d, e are the "logos" you're referring to, right? because I don't see anything cut off. Change the width of the #container and run it and it puts as many in place as there is room for.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was totally wrong on how the overflow worked. HAHA thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I might approach it using jQuery but you'll probably want to go with @mikevoermans answer.

```
var sum = 0;
$("#logos>ul>li").each( function() {
    sum += $(this).width();
    if (sum > 200) {
       $(this).hide();  
    }
});
```

[​Fiddling](http://jsfiddle.net/FDkRN/4/)

Comment: All of your divs widths in that fiddle aren't adding up to > 745 (they only add up to 563)

Comment: If you want to see an impact, reduce the maximum width below 560 as [such](http://jsfiddle.net/FDkRN/14/)

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this, but it's a bad practice.

css

```
#logos li { display:none; }
```

​

```
$("#logos ul li").each(function(){
    if ($(this).parents("#logos").width() < 200) 
        $(this).show();
});​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ocanal/FDkRN/7/

Answer (score 0):

This will add up the total logo widths and hide all logos after a certain max width is met:

```
​​$(document).ready(function(){

var maxWidth = 200;
var totalWidth = 0;

    $('#logos li').each(function(){
        var logoWidth = parseInt($(this).width());

        if(totalWidth + logoWidth > maxWidth)
        {
           $(this).hide();   
        }

        totalWidth += logoWidth;
    });


});​
```

You could also use `$(this).remove()` if you want to remove the element rather than just hiding.

Comment: It looks like `$(this).width()` is a better way to find the width unless you are avoiding some unforeseen consequences by asking for css('width') and removing the px designation.

Comment: you have it reversed. I want to hide the logos first. Then show the ones that fit in the space only.

Comment: @veeTrain you're right, `.width()` returns the value with no unit of measurement. GermanMan, in practice the user will never see the logos before `.ready()` is fired, but if you want to be sure you could set `#logos li { display:none; }` and show them instead of hiding.